# How to let Parent refresh data if I add data in the child controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to add some data in teh child controller, after I submit added data in the child controller,I need parent controller reload the data. Here is some code sample:

```
 function parentCtr(){
       $scope.getReportsView = function() {
            ReportService
                .getReportListView(
                    $scope.Headerinfo.expenseReportID)
                .then(
                    function(reportInformation) {
                        $scope.Expensereports =    reportInformation.expensesList.expReport;
                        if ($scope.Expensereports != null && $scope.Expensereports.length > 0) {
                            $scope.noExpense = false;
                        }
                    });
        };
} 
in the child controller:
I have function like:
$scope.addData = function(data){
   addDataService.add(data).then(function())
}
```

I am using bootstrap $modal to create add data popup, the child controller is for thsi modal:

```
<div ng-contrlooer='parentCtr'>
 {{Expensereports }}
    <button ng-click='openPopup'>Add Data</>
</div>
```

waht I want is after I add data successfully in the child controller, I need to let $scope.getReportsView() in the parent controller run again to refresh table.
The added data is part of $scope.Expensereports which is I used in parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after seeing your code and your HTML, and with your explanation of how you're calling the child controller in a modal, I think what's going on here is while you logically have a parent child relationship, no such relationship exists between the controllers. If one does, then `$scope.$parent should give you access to the parent scope.

Since that doesn't seem to be the case, my suggestion would be simply to call `$scope.getReportsView` from the "parent" scope when you return from the modal.

Comment: I add $scope.$parent.getReportsView(); into addData function, but it didn't work it shows $scope.$parent.getReportsView() is not a function in console.

Comment: delete $scope. $parent is a separate object. Oops, not in the controller, in the view.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, what u mean in the view?

Comment: In the view - your HTML - the $scope is not necessary in front of the $parent. In the controller, it is.

Comment: Can you post the HTML? I am assuming that you are creating the child controller while the parent controller is still in scope. If not $parent will not point to anything.

Comment: well, all I need is recall the getReportsView() function, I didn't change anything in the view. I did like this:$scope.attachEbinAttachments = function(receipts) {
            ExpenseEntryService.attachImages(receipts, $scope.reportID, $scope.expenseID).then(function(response) {
                $scope.$parent.getReportsView();
            });
        }; in my child controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90648/discussion-between-linyuanxie-and-mike-feltman).

Comment: I'm calling it a day for now, but I want to see the HTML to make sure that you have a parent/child relationship between the controllers.

Comment: I use bootstrap $modal to create a popup to add data, so the child controller is for this modal popup.

Comment: I added Html you can see that